# Why pdflatex on overleaf and my laptop gives different output?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am trying to compile a latex package.

My question is: when I compile this package on overleaf, the resultant pdf contains "List of abbreviations," but on my laptop, it does not print.

Here is the minimal example of main tex file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, nobind]{unilim} 
\title{Conception}
\author{Ragh}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor = {Rémy BOUCHÉ}, pdftitle = {Thèse de doctorat}}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{4g}{4G}{Fourth Generation Mobile Radio}

\begin{document}

\setglossarystyle{alttree} 
\renewcommand{\glstreenamebox}[2]{\makebox[#1][r]{#2~~ -- ~~}} 
\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\glsfindwidesttoplevelname[\currentglossary]}

\printglossary[title=List of abbreviations]

\section{Examples}
\gls{4g}

\end{document}
```

The link of the unilim.cls file is : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xaYacE8oNGOqhb2m1zmYr77YrFMDzJ2K/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [glossaries](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries). The missing part on the left is a list of abbreviations. The list is read by `glossaries` from `*.gls` file but the file is not created by LaTeX. You have to run the external program `makeindex` in the terminal to create it. However, `makeindex` also requires information to process., which is created when you compile the document with `glosaaries`.

Essentially, `glossaries` does two things: create/update two files: `*.ist` and `*.glo` and simultaneously read from `*.gls` if it exists. The list will only be updated if you run `makeindex` (see more details on pages 14--17 of the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries)).

A few remarks. You would need to compile the document multiple times before and after `makeindex` is invoked. Consider using `latexmk`, which conveniently runs LaTeX as many times as the document needs. Assuming the main document is `main.tex`, this should be your routine:

```bash
$ latexmk -pdf main
$ makeindex -s main.ist -o main.gls main.glo
$ latexmk -pdf main
```

Then, PDF should look exactly like on the right. If something goes wrong with `latexmk`, try to append `-norc`. Also, change `-pdf` to `-pdflua` if you want to compile a document by `lualatex`. You can use `latexmk -C` before compilation to clear the project folder but `*.ist`, `*.glo` and `*.gls` will have to be deleted manually (by default).

I stress this gain, you have to run `makeindex` every time you have changed acronyms to update the list.

When it comes to editors, I am afraid `makeindex` is not automatically included in default routines. You have to add a rule by yourself.

Goof luck.

Comment: Your solution fails to use bib tex citations

Comment: The routine needs to be updated to cover citations which you haven't mentioned, have you! `bibtex` needs to be invoked after compiling a document for the first time and then twice afterwards. Get yourself familiar with the [bibliography](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex#Enter_\(\mathrm{Bib\TeX}\)), specifically the [bibtex](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex#Enter_\(\mathrm{Bib\TeX}\)). If it doesn't work, ask a new question because this one is not about the use of bibliography but `glossaries`.